# Is my Windows 2003 Server a Terminal Server without setting it up to be so?

Tags: windows-server-2003

Last month I posted a question about installing and setting up a SSL Certificate onto my Windows 2003 Server.  Thankfully, I received a couple of good answers and am now prepared to try them out.

The question I had at the time was this:

"In my office, there is one Network Server running Windows 2003 SP2. This IS NOT A WEB SERVER. There are 7 workstations, each one is running Windows XP. Two of the workstations are setup with Credit Card scanners for my clients. I have a Static IP address, so as to connect to my office Server by using the Windows RDP feature.

The Credit Card Scanner people now want me to "configure terminal services to utilize SSL for authentication of the server." They are concerned about a "Man in the middle attack."

If I connect with a SSL seller, such as Godaddy, or for that matter, any seller, and in turn purchase a SSL Certificate, do I download this certificate? Do I have to configure it on the server to issue PKI's. I'm just not sure on what to do, after downloading a certificate. What exactly are the steps that follow once I purchase a SSL certificate?"

Since asking the above question, I have purchased a standard SSL certificate from Godaddy.  But before I attempt anything else, I have a couple more questions that are important to me to know.  The company that controls the Credit Cards Software says the following:

"The remote host is running Terminal Services which is configured to allow Remote Desktop clients,"  etc.  They go on to say that this is a risk because there isn't any way for a remote desktop to know that it's connecting the the correct Terminal Service.

They say that to remedy this problem I have to "Configure Terminal Services to utilize  SSL Authentication of the server."

What I'm wondering is this:  Is my Windows 2003 Server considered a "Terminal Service" already?  Or do I have to give Windows 2003 Server a "Role" to be a "Terminal Service," and in turn, configure it to have a SSL Certificate?  Why I'm asking is because I'm confused.  The Credit Card people know that I'm using RDP to access my Server from home, because they refer to my Server as running Terminal Services.

I've never knowingly set up my Server to be a Terminal Server.  But there is a configuration wizard for "Setting up the Terminal Server."

If my Server is a "Terminal Server" already, then is all that I have to do now is configure it?

Any response is greatly needed, because I don't want to try anything else until I hear back from someone in the know.

Answer (score 1):

Your Server is not a Terminal Server, you are probably the Admin running Remote administration mode or "Remote Desktop for Administrators"

You need to buy a Terminal Server License and Terminal Server Cals from Microsoft and set it up correctly to do as the Credit Card people require.

The problem is you can not get Terminal Server for 2003 anymore, you have to buy Temrinal Server for 2008 and then MS will assist you in getting 2003 working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that's a really long question just to ask the question in subject.

Windows Server machines (I'm sure about 2008 and 2008R2) allow up to two remote connections to a single instance for administrative purposes. If you want more, you have to buy Terminal Services licence and setup the role.